# Dynamic object literal in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object-literal

Is it possible to creat an object literal on the fly? 
Like this:

```
var arr = [ 'one', 'two', 'three' ]; 

var literal = {}; 

for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{
   // some literal push method here! 

  /*  literal = {
        one : "", 
        two : "",
        three : ""
    }  */ 
}
```

Thus I want the result to be like this:

```
 literal = {
        one : "", 
        two : "",
        three : ""
    }
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
for ( var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; ++i ) {
    literal[arr[i]] = "something";
}
```

I also took the liberty of optimising your loop :)

Comment: Even more compact would be `for(var i in arr) { literal[arr[i]] = ''; }` :)

Comment: @Tatu, you shouldn't loop through arrays using the `for..in` construct.

Comment: Better would be `var i = arr.length; while (i--) { literal[arr[i]] = "something" }`

Answer (score 4):

Use this in your loop:

```
literal[arr[i]] = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) for the sake of simplicity:

```
for (const key of arr) {
   literal[key] = "";
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be let key?

Comment: @marko You can use const instead of let, if you don't reassign the variable inside the block, but this is not the case here, just accessing its value directly.