# Passing in dynamic key:value pairs to an object literal?

Tags: javascript

I am using this slice of code (shown below) in an attempt to populate the object literal named  `Parameters` inside the for loop. I need the `key:value` pair to be assigned in conjunction with the loops iterating `i` variable, as such: `{key_1:chunks[1],key_2:chunks[2]}`. However, my code isn't working. The `'key_'+i` is not being reflected in the literal.

There's something I am missing here, obviously. Can someone tell me what it is?...Thanks.

```
var Parameters=[];
var len = chunks.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var key='key_'+i
    obj= { key : chunks[i]};
   Parameters.push(obj)
}
```

Comment: Similar question that may be helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998735/dynamic-object-literal-in-javascript

Answer (score 31, accepted):

EDIT: Use `var obj = {}; obj[key] = chunks[i];`

Because ECMAScript treats the `key` in this `{key:1}` as literal.

Comment: Yes made a typo in the question only. Should have been `var Parameters=[];`. The question/problem still stands though.

Answer (score 5):

ES2015 ([via Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=const%20key%20%3D%20%22foo%22%3B%0Aconst%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%20%5Bkey%5D%3A%201%20%7D%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log(obj)%3B)) Supports dynamic keys:

```
const Parameters=[];
const len = chunks.length;
for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    const key = `key_${i}`;
    obj = { [key] : chunks[i]};
    Parameters.push(obj);
}
```

(note the brackets around the key)

Or better yet:

```
const Parameters = chunks.map((c, i) => ({ [`key_${i}`]: c }));
```

Answer (score 0):

same can be used for lookup: obj[key] . Do remmeber obj.key will look for key in object

```
var obj = {
    test:1
}


var key = 'test'
obj.test = obj[key] = 1
```

Here obj.key will not work