# Using variable name in JS object?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I defined a variable which will get user's input:

```
var input = USER_INPUT;
```

then, I create an object which will use this `input` as an variable name inside the object:

```
var obj = { input: Car.newCar(...)}
```

Then,  I try to access the `obj[input]`, but it returns to me **undefined**. Is it so that in javascript, I can not use variable as an object's variable name?

If I would like to define a object which has vary variable name and variable value, how can I do?

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119324/passing-in-dynamic-keyvalue-pairs-to-an-object-literal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry changed my answer after re-reading the question

```
var USER_INPUT = 'something';
var obj = {};
obj[USER_INPUT] = 'value';

obj.something ; //# => value
obj['something'] ; //# => value

obj[USER_INPUT]; //# => value
```

Comment: no, he wants to access it like you do with PHP indices. input being a variable and not fixed string

Comment: I know I was in the midst of changing my answer which I now have done. Note to self: More haste less spead :)

Comment: here, have this +1 for your troubles :)

Answer (score 2):

So I guess you want the store the input under a key named after the input itself.
You can assign the value returned by `Car.newCar()` by using the `[]` method:

```
var input = "some text";
var obj = {};

obj[input] = Car.newCar();
```