# How to replace data by a variable in .$getJSON method

Tags: jquery, variables, getjson

Quick question:

How can I replace `data` by a variable?

```
$.getJSON('getdata.php', {data: 'hello'}, function(jsonResult) {
```

Just to be clear, i do not mean `'hello'`

Comment: you want to use unic variables in the return ? instead all the result in one variable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing in dynamic key:value pairs to an object literal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119324/passing-in-dynamic-keyvalue-pairs-to-an-object-literal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var someVar = '???',
    dataObj = {};

dataObj[someVar] = 'hello';

$.getJSON('getdata.php', dataObj, function(jsonResult) { ... })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using the following:

```
var myData = {};
var keyName = 'example';

myData[keyName] = 'hello';

$.getJSON('getdata.php', myData, function(jsonResult) {
```