# Add dynamic key, value pairs to JavaScript array or hash table

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to add a key value pair to an existing javascript associative array. The key needs to be a variable. This is for JSON encoding. I realize there are many plugins and frameworks for this, but I want a simple answer.

```
ary.push({name: val});
```

where `ary` is a new array, `name` is a variable containing the key, `val` is the value of this entry.

I'm doing this in a `jQuery` loop that iterates through form fields.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing in dynamic key:value pairs to an object literal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119324/passing-in-dynamic-keyvalue-pairs-to-an-object-literal) --- please use the search before you ask a question.

Comment: Do you want `ary` = [ key: value, key: value, ...]` or `ary = [{key: value}, {key: value}, ... ]` ?

Answer (score 216):

### In ES6...

In ES6, you can use a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Computed_object_property_names_and_destructuring);

```
ary.push({[name]: val});
```

However, given this is ES6 syntax, the usual caveats apply; [this will not work in some browsers](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-destructuring,_assignment_computed_properties) (noticably, IE and Edge 13)... although Babel will transpile this for you.

---

### Without ES6 (legacy browser support)...

You need to define an object and use square bracket notation to set the property;

```
var obj = {};

obj[name] = val;

ary.push(obj);
```

If you get the urge to read into it more, see [this article](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/square_brackets.html) on the differences between square bracket and dot notation.

Comment: This is the answer. Thank You! i was enting up with 
ary[]
company "kim corp"
email "eml1" 
when i declares the array as Array

Comment: If this is your answer, you should mark it as such, so Matt get's credit, and people can easily see which answer worked for you.

Comment: This helped me out. I had multiple name/value pairs in an array object - e.g. in PHP: `$test = array();
$test[] = array ("description" => "first", "identifier" => "1");`. To add to that in JavaScript it is just `var obj = {}; obj["description"] = "second"; obj["identifier"] = 2; ary.push(obj);` where ary is the JavaScript variable that was assigned the PHP array.

Comment: Especially the first. ES6 syntax does exactly as I expected. I get a plain key-value pair with the "dynamic" keyname. So it doesn't work in IE... what else is new.

Answer (score 41):

```
var ary = [];

function pushToAry(name, val) {
   var obj = {};
   obj[name] = val;
   ary.push(obj);
}

pushToAry("myName", "myVal");
```

Having just fully read your question though, all you need is the following

```
$(your collection of form els).serializeArray();
```

Good old jQuery

Answer (score 27):

An "associative array" is really just an object.  You don't use push, you just assign properties to the object:

```
ary[name] = val;
```

Comment: It should do that i agree. I'll post all the code and hope you can see where the mistake is

Comment: this is the best answer. very simple, and all that's needed if you already have a hash defined.

Answer (score 7):

The following code will help you

```
ary.push( {[name]: val} );
```

See below example

```
let allData = [{name: "Cat", type: "Animal"}]
let finalData: any = [];
for (let i = 0; i < allData.length; i++)
{
  let obj = allData[i];
  for (let KEY in obj)
  {
    //Pushing data to other array as object
    this.finalData.push({ [KEY] : obj[KEY] });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const tStyles = [];
for (const i of iStyles) {
  const temp = {};
  temp[`${style}`] = `../dist/css/uikit.${wFile}.${style}.css`;
  tStyles.push(temp);
}
```

json : {"black-beige":"../dist/css/uikit.or.black-beige.css"}