# Updating state in react hooks (adding new object)

Tags: reactjs, functional-programming, react-hooks, use-state

I'm stuck in updating states , I'm using a function for generalising a Modal from a 3rd party framework now when I want to update the particular variable I'm stuck as dynamically its not updating ,i.e: Ex: setModalState(...oldstate,v1:{v2:false}} . Here ${v1} and ${v2} are already in old state  and I passed to function as props but javascript is not taking insted taking v1,v2;
I have attached few photos for understanding

https://res.cloudinary.com/df2q7cryi/image/upload/v1615998821/error3_svxlcw.png

https://res.cloudinary.com/df2q7cryi/image/upload/v1615998764/eroor2_enjcbc.png

https://res.cloudinary.com/df2q7cryi/image/upload/v1615998762/eroor_bz5wwf.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to use  | setModalState({...modalstate,[section]:{[purpose]:false}})}

Reference : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398535/add-dynamic-key-value-pairs-to-javascript-array-or-hash-table/9398583#:~:text=You%20need%20to%20define%20an,square%20bracket%20and%20dot%20notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398535/add-dynamic-key-value-pairs-to-javascript-array-or-hash-table/9398583#:%7E:text=You%20need%20to%20define%20an,square%20bracket%20and%20dot%20notation).