# Creating objects with variable properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to do this:

```
var sortAfter = req.query.sortAfter || '_id';
var ascending = req.query.direction || -1;
var sorted = {sortAfter: ascending};
```

But a console.log(sorted) output the following object:

```
{ sortAfter: -1 }
```

It's like the first variable is not used in the object creation...

**Question:** How do i get the object to be made of *two* variables, and not one variable and one fixed string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing in dynamic key:value pairs to an object literal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119324/passing-in-dynamic-keyvalue-pairs-to-an-object-literal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this way:

```
var sortAfter = req.query.sortAfter || '_id';
var ascending = req.query.direction || -1;
var sorted = {};
sorted[sortAfter] = ascending;
```

Answer (score 1):

In object literals, the keys are always literals, they're never variables. If you want to set a dynamic object key, you'll have to do it like this:

```
var sorted = {};
sorted[sortAfter] = ascending;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the subscript/bracket notation:

```
var sorted = {};
sorted[sortAfter] = ascending;
```

The subscript operator will convert its operand to a string,