# Create an object with dynamic property names

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do this:

```
var KEYS = {} ;

KEYS.PHONE_TYPE = 'phone-type';
KEYS.AGENT_TYPE = 'agent-type';

var myAppConfig = {
    ...
    iconMap : { 
        KEYS.PHONE_TYPE : 'icon-phone', 
        KEYS.AGENT_TYPE : 'icon-headphones'
    };
    ...
};
```

But it is failing, with a message: `Expected ':' and instead saw '.'.`

How can I initialize an object using indirect (non-literal) keynames?

To be clear, the result I want is:

```
{
    'phone-type' : 'icon-phone',
    'agent-type' : 'icon-headphones'
}
```

Comment: and [Use a concatenated (dynamic) string as JavaScript object key?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9708192/218196)

Comment: and [Dynamic object literal in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1998735/218196)

Comment: and [Is it possible to add dynamically named properties to JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1184123/218196)

Comment: I guess I get your point! :) But I assure you I looked for it before!

Answer (score 14):

If you're using ES6 (or something like Babel/browserify), you can write it like this:

```
iconMap : { 
    [KEYS.PHONE_TYPE] : 'icon-phone', 
    [KEYS.AGENT_TYPE] : 'icon-headphones'
};
```

Answer (score 7):

You would have to add those properties separately using bracket notation:

```
var myAppConfig = {
    ...
    iconMap : { }
    ...
};

myAppConfig.iconMap[ KEYS.PHONE_TYPE ] = 'icon-phone';
myAppConfig.iconMap[ KEYS.AGENT_TYPE ] = 'icon-headphones';
```

Comment: Thanks. I am still surprised that javascript has no built-in support for initialization of an object with dynamic keynames. Python can do this for dictionaries, and it is very convenient. I guess this comes from the fact that the quotes are optional in javascript properties.

Comment: I guess JS abandoned that possibility by allowing unquoted attribute names, Python avoids this by requiring quoted attribute names.