# Use string as property name

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript object defined below:

```
var user = { name:'Allen', age:'26', gender:'male'}
```

I want to reference the user property user.name via string such as below:

```
var string = "name";
var username = user.string;
```

This doesn't work, how would I go about this?

EDIT: just to clarify, I want user.string to be the equivalent of user.name - some might ask why I don't just call user.name, and this is because I have an array of strings that I would like to evaluate for the object.

Comment: var username = user[string]?

Comment: @cokeman19 not quite...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic object property name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamic-object-property-name) and [a pile of others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832583/create-an-object-with-dynamic-property-names#comment26027295_17832583)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd do something like

```
var string = 'name';
var username = user[string];
```

to access the property in the string.

Right now your code is trying to access an undefined 'string' property on the user.

Comment: this works! i guess objects can be evaluated as dictionaries as well, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure about what you mean. You can access the name property with `user.name`. It will return Allen.

```
var user = { name:'Allen', age:26, gender:'male' }

var name = user.name; // 'Allen'
var age = user.age; // 26
var gender = user.gender; // 'male'
```

Comment: basically, I want to get the REFERENCE of the string. for instance, if I have a var x = "name", then I want user.x to be the equivalent of user.name