# How to add label to js array?

Tags: javascript

Hi I am looking to create an array that looks similar to this

```
const userList = {
  123: "Tom",
  124: "Michael",
  125: "Christin",
};
```

it contains both value and label, what I tried so far

```
let raw =  []
for (let x in data) {
  raw.push(data[x].facility_name : data[x].id)
}
```

but it didn't work because "," was expected, if someone can help please

Comment: Your output you want is an object, but for some reason you defined it as an array?

Comment: [What is an Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) -- [What is an Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

Comment: What are `facility_name` and `id`? Can you show what result you're trying to get?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832583/create-an-object-with-dynamic-property-names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing arrays and objects. You need to add a key to an object not push. I kept it as a `for in` loop, but a `for of` loop would make more sense.

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, facility_name: "foo1" },
  { id: 2, facility_name: "foo2" },
  { id: 3, facility_name: "foo3" }
];

let raw = {};
for (let x in data) {
  raw[data[x].id] = data[x].facility_name;
}

console.log(raw);
```

How I would code it using reduce.

```js
var data = [
  { id: 1, facility_name: "foo1" },
  { id: 2, facility_name: "foo2" },
  { id: 3, facility_name: "foo3" }
];

const raw = data.reduce(function (acc, facility) {
  acc[facility.id] = facility.facility_name;
  return acc;
}, {})
console.log(raw);
```

Answer (score 0):

IF your data has nested objects then you might do this:

```
let raw = {};
for(x in data)
{
    raw[data[x].facility_name] = data[x].id;
}
```

This is useful when you want to get rid of duplicates.