# Define object with variables for property names

Tags: javascript, variables, object-literal

I have a problem in declaring a inicialiting an object. When I define an object and pass by reference a string does not recognize me and fails. The object is as follows:

```
markerGroups = {"america": [], "europa": [], "asia": [],"africa": [], "oceania": [] };
```

Well, it works correctly, but if I change, for example, "america" ​​putting var  amer = "america"​​, like this:

```
var amer = "america"; 
markerGroups = {amer: [], "europa": [], "asia": [],"africa": [], "oceania": [] };
```

It does not work. What i have to do for resolve this?

Comment: Unlike Python dicts, in a JavaScript Object Literal, property names are *always* literal values and are *never* expressions: `{a: "foo"}` and `{'a': "foo"}` and `{"a": "foo"}` are all equivalent.

Comment: I don't know if it's a duplicate of *that* question, as the *question* seems to start where I think the *answer* to this should end.. (that being said, there are plenty of duplicates)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708192/use-a-concatenated-dynamic-string-as-javascript-object-key?lq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998735/dynamic-object-literal-in-javascript?lq=1

Comment: I'm sorry if there are a duplicate :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this;

```
var markerGroups = {}
var amer = "america"; 
markerGroups[amer] = [];
```

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, you don't need to quote your object keys.  So `amer: []` is creating the literal key "amer".

You need to use the `[]` method to do this:

```
var amer = "america"; 

markerGroups = {...};
markerGroups[amer] = [];
```